# UIButton change font and text at the same time

Tags: ios, uibutton

We have a `UIButton` in our app that we change back and forth between displaying a normal system font string and a [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io) icon (which is just a unicode character that is specific to their font). We can switch back and forth between these just fine, except that iOS animates the two changes one after the other, so there is a brief amount of time where the text shows up strangely after the first change but before the second. I tried using `UIView.beginAnimations` with its `commitAnimations` counterpart, as well as `animateWithDuration:animations:`, but neither had any effect.

How can I change both the text and font at the same time?

**Edit:** Updated with code as per comment

```
func changeToSend() {
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 15)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

func changeToMicroPhone() {
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 24)
    sendButton.setTitle("\u{f130}", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    func changeToSend() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation { 
            self.sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 15)
            self.sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }

    func changeToMicroPhone() {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 24)
            self.sendButton.setTitle("\u{f130}", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems like your solution is working for `changeToMicroPhone` but not `changeToSend`